# Post a link on facebook wall - picture doesn't apper

Tags: facebook

When i post a video link on FB wall, the first time the thumbnail appears,
then i delete the link from the box, and write it again, this and now the thumping dissapers.

this is a link for example, the first time facebook will show it.

http://reshet.tv/Shows/Dating_In_The_Dark/video/.aspx?vml=211830

Comment: what is your posting codes? or you are just using Facebook interface instead of Facebook API ?

Comment: im not sure i understand your question.

Comment: Im just taking the link, on the page code i have metadata that include picture and text on the page.   As i understand it should take this things and show it. it does it the dirst time and the other time not.

Comment: you mean you didn't use any SDK ( JavaScript / PHP / iOS / Android ) ?

Comment: yes, just take the links and facebook should take all the information from my page

Comment: it's Facebook's mechanism. Can't help. Assuming you are the writer of the page, you have already put the correct OG tags to the page head, so nothing you can do.

Comment: Do you maybe know how can I contact facebook to prevent such cases ?

Comment: and yes I have all the og tags

Comment: Facebook Help Center can help.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the conversation above, it's Facebook's mechanism. Can't help. Assuming you are the writer of the page, you have already put the correct OG tags to the page head, so nothing you can do.